# Disable certain part of fragment for scrolling even though it's inside a nested scrollview

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout, android-nestedscrollview

Currently I am finishing the last details of my project and I am trying to keep a certain part inside a nested scrollview to stay on top of the screen and let only the recyclerview scroll.

This is the code I have right now:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/marktplaats_refresh"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:tint="#9F000000"
                app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/offer_bg"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/verkoopEenProduct"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="Verkoop een product"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/light_contact_buttons"
                android:hint="Zoek in marktplaats"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView33"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView32"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:text="Marktplaats"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/verkoopEenProduct"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Hier vind u alles wat u nodig\nhebt voor uw praktijk"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView32"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView34"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Alle producten"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView14"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/marktplaats_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView34"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:translationX="-20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:text="&#x279C;"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And this is my kotlin

```
class MarktplaatsOverview : ApplicationFragment(){
    var products: Array<MarketModel> = arrayOf()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_marktplaats, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        marktplaats_refresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            refreshData()
            marktplaats_refresh.isRefreshing = false
        }

        button11.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_marktplaatsOverview_to_more)
        }
        button5.requestFocus()

        refreshData()

        verkoopEenProduct.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_marktplaatsOverview_to_marktplaatsDetail)
        }
    }

    private fun refreshData() {
        if (DataStorage.market.isNotEmpty()) {
            setupRecyclerView()
        } else {
            SharedInstance.api.getAllMarketItems {
                if (isAdded) {
                    setupRecyclerView()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView(){
        SharedInstance.api.getAllMarketItems {
            products = DataStorage.market
            val xLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true)
            xLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
            marktplaats_recyclerview.layoutManager = xLayoutManager
            marktplaats_recyclerview.adapter = MarktplaatsAdapter(products)
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this awkward problem? I've been trying to do some restructuring of the swiperefreshlayout, scrollviews and constraints but no succes so far.
I also can't find anything on the internet where someone wants the same as me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question description, I am assuming that you face an issue that recycler view scroll or take focus automatically while you open screen and you need to stick layout at the top so pass this field on your parent layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

or replace your SwipeRefreshLayout

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/marktplaats_refresh"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I've tried your solution but this does not change anything for my app unfortunately. I have an imageview which is 225 dp on top and some stuff on top of that imageview. All that needs to stay in position even though I need to have swipe to refresh enabled, other than that I want only the recyclerview to scroll and collapse into the imageview on top, and of course vice versa when scrolling the opposite direction.